# WL.Server.getClientRequest() returns null in WL adapter procedure method

Tags: adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to get access to the request headers sent in from WL client side. When I use this

```
var request = WL.Server.getClientRequest();
```

in the adapter procedure call, it returned null and causing the error on the line after

```
var userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

with error as: Cannot call method "getHeader" of null

Is there any special setup needed in order to use this WL api call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like adapter's invocation used in Studio is blocking the access to incoming client request. Basically speaking getClientRequest() is not working when you're using Eclipse's "Invoke Worklight Procedure" option. What you can do here is following - once you do "Invoke Worklight Procedure" a browser will open with URL similar to this

```
   http://{serverIP}:{serverPort}/{projectName}/dev/invoke?adapter={adapterName}&procedure={procedureName}&parameters={params}
```

Remove /dev component from URL. So your URL will look like this

```
   http://{serverIP}:{serverPort}/{projectName}/invoke?adapter={adapterName}&procedure={procedureName}&parameters={params}
```

This will make sure that adapter is invoked not via development preview but directly from WL server and getClientRequest() API will be fully functional.

P.S. You might hit a behaviour when "Invoke Worklight Procedure" is not opening an external browser window but instead showing the invocation result in Eclipse window. This depends on Eclipse version you're using and can be easily changed in Eclipse's preferences -> General -> Web Browser -> Use external web browser.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference in Eclipse. By following your steps, I am able to verify the request header when invoke the procedure from Eclipse through external web browser. Now, I am moving to the client side to invoke the procedure with following code. Strangely, nothing happened. No incoming req to the adapter and nothing is printed out in the console. I used iOS simulator to test the code and used Safari develop option to trace the code. I verified that all information is passed in to the WL code correctly. Any idea?

Comment: sorry, the comment ended before I can past in my code. Here is the code:function callFromNative(data)
{
 var userid = data.userid? data.userid : data;
 
 var invocationData = {
   adapter: 'LoginAdapter',
   procedure: 'checkUserid',
   parameters: [userid],
 };
   
 WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
  onSuccess: checkUseridSuccess,
  onFailure: checkUseridFailure
 }); 
}

function checkUseridSuccess(result)
{
 WL.Logger.debug("check userid succeeded");
  
}

function checkUseridFailure(error)
{
 WL.Logger.debug("check userid failed with error: " + JSON.stringify(error)); 
}

Comment: trying for a good format for the code: `function callFromNative(data) { var userid = data.userid? data.userid : data; var invocationData = { adapter: 'LoginAdapter', procedure: 'checkUserid', parameters: [userid], }; WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, { onSuccess: checkUseridSuccess, onFailure: checkUseridFailure });  } function checkUseridSuccess(result) { WL.Logger.debug("check userid succeeded"); } function checkUseridFailure(error) { WL.Logger.debug("check userid failed with error: " + JSON.stringify(error));  }`

Comment: never mind, the same code now started working and received the adapter response. Not sure what was going on earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The API `WL.Server.getClientRequest()` only works when invoked from a client (from a device or even from the preview) and not when invoked directly from Eclipse.

For example:
In the adapter XML I've created a procedure:

```
<procedure name="getUserAgent"/>
```

In the adapter JavaScript I've created a function called `getUserAgent` that will return the userAgent to the client:

```
function getUserAgent() {
    var request = WL.Server.getClientRequest(),
        userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
    return {userAgent : userAgent};
}
```

In the client Javascript I've created a function that is called from the `wlCommonInit`. The function invokes the adapter procedure and the returned userAgent is displayed in an alert:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    getUserAgent();
}

function getUserAgent () {
    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(
            {
                adapter: 'getClientRequest',
                procedure: 'getUserAgent',
            },
            {
                onSuccess : onSuccessGetUserAgent,
                onFailure : onFailureGetUserAgent
            }
        );
}

function onSuccessGetUserAgent (data) {
    alert('userAgent: ' + data.invocationResult.userAgent);
}

function onFailureGetUserAgent () {
    alert('Failure');
}
```